# how do i set the browseraction popup width and height?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

here is my problem:
http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/5391/88030081.gif

here is my simple page:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
URL fixing provided by none
</body>
</html>
```

what do I need to do?
I see other extensions with width and height set to just fine, and i only enter some little text and I get linebreak,
this is the only thing I get stucked in developing my extension- this is just an example of what happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
body {min-width:300px;min-height:300px;}
```